# Windows server 2012 R2 set default site in iis with out changing port number

Tags: iis, iis-8

i would like configure website under port 80 in iis8. 
i need to setup this without changing ipaddress and portnumber.
but it is showing following error message.
could you please help us to find the solution we are running out of time.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can solve this one of two ways:

1. Stop the other website that is using the same IP and port
   or
2. Add a host name to your website's binding that makes it unique from the other site(s).

In IIS, each site must have a unique combination of host name, IP address and port number.

Comment: How can i check other website is running on same port is there any command to check that, in IIS only one website is running that too in default. we have tried by adding hostname. but our requirement is something different we can add/change hostname in iis.

Comment: If you only have a few websites and you're trying to troubleshoot the problem, just stop the other sites briefly to see if you can get your site to come up. Otherwise, you can use appcmd to view a list of other sites with their bindings, for ex: appcmd list site /bindings:http/*:80: For more info on appcmd, http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc772200%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Answer (score -1):

There is always a default website on IIS.

Locate it on your left pan of IIS manager by clicking on sites, click on Default Web site and check your right pan, locate the manage website section and stop it.

Then add your website by right-clicking on site and add website, configure it and use default application pool